# Fast thread syncronization

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm working on a system that have multiple threads and one shared object. There is a number of threads that do read operations very often, but write operations are rare, maybe 3 to 5 per day.

I'm using rwlock for synchronization but the lock acquisition operation it's not fast enough since it happens all the time. So, I'm looking for a faster way of doing it.

Maybe a way of making the write function atomic or looking all threads during the write. Portability it's not a hard requirement, I'm using Linux with GCC 4.6.

Comment: it would be helpful to know more about the problem you are trying to solve. For instance how large is the critical section for readers/writers. And what are the consistency requirements between threads. Since writes are so infrequent does it matter if a thread reads stale data?  Depending on what you are doing there are many possible low level optimization that may or may not make sense.

Comment: There's no problem in reading stale data, the problema is read data during the write operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use a multiple objects rather than a single one. Instead of actually sharing the object, create an object that holds the object and an atomic count, then share a *pointer* to this structure among the threads.

[Assuming that there is only one writer] Each reader will get the pointer, then atomically increment the counter and use the object, after reading, atomically decrement the counter. The writer will create a new object that holds a copy of the original and modify it. Then perform an atomic swap of the two pointers. Now the problem is releasing the old object, which is why you need the count of the readers. The writer needs to continue checking the count of the old object until all readers have completed the work at which point you can delete the old object.

If there are multiple writers (i.e. there can be more than one thread updating the variable) you can follow the same approach but with writers would need to do a compare-and-swap exchange of the pointer. If the pointer from which the updated copy has changed, then the writer restarts the process (deletes it's new object, copies again from the pointer and retries the CAS)

Comment: That's right there's only one writer. Very clever your suggestion.

Comment: @Renato: I believe there is a race condition in the proposed solution, beware! In particular, one reader might have obtained the pointer, but not yet incremented the reference count. If at that point the writer performs the swap and checks the reference count it will believe that there is no reader accessing the old object and think that it can effectively delete it, causing undefined behavior on the reader (access to a deleted object). I believe that can be solved by having the reference counts externally and incrementing it  *before* obtaining the pointer.

Comment: ... in the case of a single writer you might be able to make do with two versions (ensuring that the writer does not update the inactive version of the object while there are readers still using it, in the event that two writes come close enough that readers that accessed the oldest object may not have completed before the second update). This solution has a different (safer) race condition, where a reader might increment the count *after* the pointer was updated by the writer, so ti would increment the old count, but access the new object...

Comment: ... this is less of a problem, since the effect would be that the writer has to wait for all readers of the old object *and* potentially some readers of the new object before deleting, i.e. the writer might take longer than needing to reclaim the old object.

Comment: I initially understood that I should have a external counter and increment it before. Then the problem is that the writer has to update the counter too (return it to zero) so, there's no way of keep the consistency of the shared counter and pointer without synchronization method.

Comment: @Renato: The writer (assuming a single writer) does not need to update the count, but there must be separate counts for the old and the new object during an update, and as part of the update of the pointer to the object the counter must also be updated. If your platform has DCAS then you can use that, if it does not, then choosing to update the pointer and then the count will lead you to potentially a harmless inconsistency (i.e. a thread accessing the new object --read the pointer after it was updated-- might be counted as accessing the old object --counter not yet changed...

Comment: ... the effect of that is that the writer will wait for all threads accessing the old object and potentially some threads accessing the new object before being sure that it can safely remove the old object. There are other options, as for example using an *array* (of potentially only two) pairs of counter/object, and having a pointer that refers to either object. The readers would always use the active pointer, the writer would use the other object *only if* there are no readers accessing it, if there are, the writer would have to wait until the existing readers complete before updating.

Comment: After some problems due corruption, because of my stupidity, it seems to be working, although I didn't send to test in lab. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using read-copy-update with [liburcu](http://lttng.org/urcu)? This lets you avoid atomic operations and locking *entirely* on the read path, at the expense of making writes quite a bit slower. Note that some readers might see stale data for a short time, though; if you need the update to take effect immediately, it may not be the best option for you.

Comment: +1 on the library, but it is important to note that you only avoid all costs in the reader path if the kernel does not have preemption enabled, which might or not be the case of the user. Different off-the-shelf linux kernels have preemption enabled, and in those cases the trick of having the writer core wait in the kernel until all other cores have had a context switch is not sufficient and extra mechanisms have to be used. The advantage is that the library *knows* this and already has it implemented, and tested.

Comment: It could works since delay it's not the problem. I didn't known this lib. I will read about it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a spinlock, the threads will busy wait until unlocked. If the threads aren't locked for long it can be much more efficent than mutexes since the locking and unlocking is completed with less instructions.

spinlock is a part of POSIX pthread although optional so I don't know if it's implemented on your system. I used them in a C program on ubuntu but had to compile with -std=gnu99 instead of c99.

Comment: Besides I didn't tried, I think that it will not be faster than rwlock because a have a massive paralellization on read (>100) and it don't allows read paralellization.